# I need to make my SharePoint page more interactive

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

I'm new here.

I'm working with SharePoint out of the box web parts and found out it is too basic with little customization.

I need to make some web parts interactive but could not due to its limitations.

Please, can anyone suggest steps of doing it in another way? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot customize SharePoint out of the web parts.

However, you can create your own custom web parts in SharePoint using SharePoint framework (SPFx).

You can use various coding languages/frameworks with SPFx to develop interactive web parts as per your requirements.

Check these Microsoft documentations for more information:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [Overview of SharePoint client-side web parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
3. [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Also, check these GitHub repositories where you can find different SPFx code samples which will help you to get started with. If you find any web part/extension in these repositories which will be helpful to you, you can download the code for free and reuse it for your web parts.

1. [SPFx web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [SPFx extensions samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)